# C# Grouping numbers

Tags: c#

I am generating an excel output with a field that has repetitive numbers in each record. The number increments at a change of a value in another field.

```
Example: Field1     field2

           1         A
           1         A
           2         B
           3         D
           4         F
           4         F
           4         F
           5         R
```

I want 1 to represent A, 2 represent B, 3 represent D etc and not have a repeat of numbers.

Comment: Do you have the letters already and want the numbers, or vice versa?  All the sequences already guaranteed to be grouped?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to interpret your question, but perhaps you want something like this:

```
Dictionary<string,int> dict=new Dictionary<string,int>();
int counter=1;
int IdOfString(string s)
{
  int i;
  if(dict.TryGetValue(s,i))
    return i;
  else
  {
     i=counter;
     counter++;
     dict.Add(s,i);
     return i;
  }
}
```

It returns a new number for each unique string you pass into `IdOfString`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but here are some suggestions:

- you can generate a column with the numbers (1, 2, 3, etc.) and a second column with the Char formula.
  Example:

```
    [A]      [B]
    1        =Char(A1 - 64)
    2        =Char(A2 - 64)
    3        =Char(A3 - 64)
```

if you have the characters and want to obtain the values you can do the opposite by using the Code function:

```
    [A]             [B]
    =Code(A1) - 64   A
    =Code(A2) - 64   B
    =Code(A3) - 64   C
```

- Otherwise you can directly generate the values for both columns in C# by casting to char (and to int to do the opposite).

Comment: What I have is the output file. I have written code to generate the numbers. the problem is that I want a number to represent the corresponding values in field B like this: 1 - A, 2 - B, 3 -D, 4 - F not 4 - F F F, i hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Excel's Code function does exactly this: Code("A") - 64 gives 1, Code("B") - 64 gives 2, etc.  In C#: (int)'A' - 64 gives 1, (int)'B' - 64 gives 2, etc.